# Use semicolon character ";" in bash alias

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

Got a new annoying keyboard and I'm always typing `;s` instead of `ls`.

Is there a way to create a sort of alias for this?

I tried this: `alias ;s="ls"` but of course it does not work!

Comment: [unix.se] is a better fit for questions about configuring your shell for interactive use; Stack Overflow's scope is limited to specific problems you encounter while writing software.

Comment: Thank @CharlesDuffy, should I delete this post and ask there?

Comment: Let's see if they have anything already in the knowledgebase there -- hopefully they'll already have a Q&A entry that's a fit. IIRC, readline -- the library bash uses for terminal interaction -- can be configured to do simple string replacements.

Comment: ...see `bind` in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins

Comment: If you hadn't already gotten a good answer, then I'd say that migrating was the Right Thing. As it is, probably fine to let this be and be aware of [unix.se] for the future; if enough folks believe strongly it'll attract close votes or a moderator migration flag.

Comment: Well, actually the bind solution was acceptable, I think it's good the leave this here...

Comment: I leaned toward treating this as a programming question (even though it revolved around the use of a shell command) since the immediate cause involved the grammar of the shell language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot. You can escape the `;` when you run the command, but then `alias` itself informs you that the name is invalid.

```
$ alias \;s=ls
bash: alias: `;s': invalid alias name
```

You *could* define a Readline macro to replace `;s` with `ls` before the shell tries to parse it:

```
$ bind '";s": "ls"'
```

This command can be added to your `.bashrc` file. (You could add it a definition to `.inputrc`, but it is unlikely you would want to use this macro in any other Readline-aware program.)

Comment: I was wondering about a sort of strange bash black magic like naming a function like that or so... idk

Comment: Generally, "black magic" is undocumented functionality, and the better way to treat undocumented functionality is as if it doesn't exist. :)